# Android MediaPlayer to mute on a single click on Volume down botton pressed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am using Android's `MediaPlayer` in my `RingtoneService` (which is a background Service for Ringtone in my application)to ring a ringtone when my Alarm goes on and off!

on the start of Ringtone Service for alarming

```
MediaPlayer mediaSong;
mediaSong = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xyz);
mediaSong.start();
```

on stop after some time

```
mediaSong.stop();
```

Its perfect in ringing and stopping the tone.whereas, I would like to make my device silent or say mute when I click on hardware's volume button pressed when an alarm is still ringing.

some stated solutions didn't answer my requirement.Any help is appreciated, please.

Please let me know somewhere if I am unclear!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onKeyDown method in your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN ||
        keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
        mediaSong.stop
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I guess this works when if it is a foreground activity .As Ringing a ringtone is a background service how to capture  an event when app is not in foreground?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do this since it would break the OS behaviour. You could hack a solution by listening to volume settings changes via ContentObserver but I'd suggest against that. It would be better if you displayed notification along your ringtone and define an action for this notification to stop the ringtone.